# Is it possible to get SOLR DIH to ignore spatial fields for documents with invalid lat/long values?

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

Im trying to import data from an Oracle Database to SOLR index. Dabatase entities do have lat/long values and the documents in the index should have a field position. The corresponding configuration in the data-config.xml hence is

```
    <field column="LONGITUDE" name="long_d" />
    <field column="LAT" name="lat_d" />
    <field column="bl" name="position" template="${data.LAT},${data.LONGITUDE}"/>
```

where *position* field is defined  as

```
    <field name="position" type="location_rpt" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

in the schema.xml file.

The problem I've is caused by badly choosen default values 999.9 for database entries for both lat and long  which are not accepted by the DIH as import values for the position field.

So my intention is to simply omit the field *position* whenever the DB entry has erroneous default values.

Is there something I can define in the configuration file for the DataImportHandler that will give me my desired results?

Answer (score 0):

There are two stages where you can apply changes:

1. You can use a transformer inside DIH itself
2. You can use a custom update request processor (URP) chain to replace or get rid of the fields

So, for example, you could use [RegexTransformer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler#UploadingStructuredDataStoreDatawiththeDataImportHandler-TheRegexTransformer) to replace known bad values with blanks. If that (blank but present fields) causes problems, you could use [RemoveBlankFields](http://www.solr-start.com/info/update-request-processors/#RemoveBlankFieldUpdateProcessorFactory) in a custom chain to drop them.